Can DGX or HGX H100 operate without NVIDIA AI Enterprise?
I have heard that NVIDIA DGX and HGX H100 clusters require activation from supported countries and an online connection to NVIDIA servers for managing the license for their enterprise software. However, I am unsure if this requirement applies to the DGX and HGX clusters. Do I need to fulfill this requirement to use these systems effectively?
I am aware that it is possible to purchase the PCI version of the H100 and install drivers from distribution package managers like apt, yum, or pacman. But I would like to know if the same approach can be applied to the cluster setup.
For example, I would like to perform the following steps:

Install a fresh CentOS operating system on the DGX system.
Download the necessary drivers using dnf or directly from NVIDIA.
Work with the GPUs directly from the system or via the Kubernetes GPU operator.

My question is, can I perform these steps, or will the DGX system become unusable without the licensing and internet connection (except for mirrors for specific applications)? In other words, will the DGX turn into a useless piece of hardware without the required licensing and internet connectivity?
